# FS.Store.GridFS createdByTransform: false

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm try to save the image file in use the [Meteor-CollectionFS](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS)

But fail.
Image model

```
/**
 * Create collections Images
 * @type {FS.Collection}
 */
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
    stores: [
        /**
         * Use GridFS stores
         */
        new FS.Store.GridFS("original"),
        new FS.Store.GridFS("thumbnail", {
            transformWrite: function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
                gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize('32', '32', '!').stream().pipe(writeStream);
            }
        })
    ],
    filter: {
        allow: {
            contentTypes: ['image/*']
        }
    }
});
```

Next am save the image in controller

```
this.saveCroppedImage = () => {
                if (this.myCroppedImage !== '') {
                    Images.insert(this.myCroppedImage, (err, fileObj) => {
                        if (!this.newParty.images) {
                            this.newParty.images = [];
                        }

                        console.log(fileObj);

                        this.newParty.images.push(fileObj);
                        this.cropImgSrc = undefined;
                        this.myCroppedImage = '';
                    });
                }
            };
```

fileObj not have url() methods. And if try to get image link, catch 503 error. But if put link in a browser - image exist

Answer (score 0):

If you work with angular-meteor and image._id exists in collection - not subscribe on collection images - use this function on the client

```
var getImageLink = function (imageId, store = "thumbnail") {
            var authToken = FS.Utility.btoa(JSON.stringify({
                authToken: Accounts._storedLoginToken() || '',
            }));
            return "/cfs/files/images/"+imageId+"?token="+authToken+"&store="+store;
        }
```